# Why won't MKMapView display maps where the view is just 3m to 10m across?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, cgaffinetransform

I've got a MKMapView that is 194x427 (InterfaceBuilder size) and I'm trying to make the map region display a map that's about 3m across. But the smallest map region I can seem to make is 162m across. How can I zoom in or transform the map so that it's more blown up? I tried applying a CGAffineTransform but it doesn't seem to work right; the map always re-updates and undoes whatever the transform did. How can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the solution is to put the MKMapView into a subview, which I called mapClipper. Then what we do is capture an image of the MKMapView and add it as a subview to mapClipper, on top of the MKMapView itself, so now what we see is the image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mapView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[_mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *mapImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
mapImage.tag = 666;
UIView *oldMapImage = [_mapClipper viewWithTag:666];
[oldMapImage removeFromSuperview];
[_mapClipper addSubview:mapImage];
```

Now to enlarge the map more than what the MKMapView would typically allow, just use CGAffineTransformScale to modify the scale of mapImage.transform. Given a scale factor that you determine from the map's actual represented meters per point compared to what you want it to be, called scaleFactor, use something like this:

```
mapImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(mapImage.transform,scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
```